# Is there a way to show the version of a document as seen by a colour blind reader?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, accessibility

I’m creating a number of coloured grids with TikZ, which look something like this:

[image]

This exercise is designed to demonstrate reflections and rotational symmetry. It’s important that the individual colours be distinguishable, and a problem in the past has been colour blindness. Readers who are colour blind can’t distinguish the individual colours, which makes it harder to see the symmetries.

I’m using the tool [Colour Oracle](http://colororacle.cartography.ch/) to test the colours against deuteranopia (green deficiency), protanopia (red deficiency) and tritanopia (blue deficiency), but I’d like to be able to output a PDF that retains these filters, without recalculating every colour by hand.

**Is there a package that I can use at compile time, or a PDF tool that allows me to simulate colour blindness?**

As a bonus, the ability to simulate the desaturation that comes from using a projector in a lit room would also be useful.

(If anybody is interested in the exercise the original version is a problem [on the NRICH website](http://nrich.maths.org/900). I’m updating it as part of my summer work.)

Comment: I didn't check it but maybe you can define a new colormap via `xcolor` (which TikZ uses under the hood). For what is worth, I'm color blind too and what I see is equal rows of 1-3 and equal columns of (1-5),(2-4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import the file into Adobe Illustrator or PhotoShop (CS4 or later) and use the ``Color Blindness Filters'' which Adobe has implemented:

http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/illustrator.edu.html

Blog post on it here: http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2008/12/supporting_colorblind_accesibility_in_cs4.html

If it's just flat areas of text or color, you could export to .html and view it here: http://colorfilter.wickline.org/

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but far less costly as WillAdams' answer, The Gimp seems to have such a capacity through [this plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/24885) (and is able to open a PDF as a picture)