Can I simulate colour-blindness (in Beamer / TikZ)
I'm putting together a talk on figures for publications, and one point I want to make is about them being accessible to colour-blind readers/viewers.  So far I've been using ColorOracle to simulate what a colour-blind person might see (it's also handy for simulating greyscale).  However this has a few downsides: It isn't an option using someone else's machine, like one of our seminar room setups, it doesn't play nicely with multiple monitors, and as soon as you click on another window, the display reverts to normal.
This is probably wishful thinking, but is there a simple way to switch the contents of my slides to a simulated view? Just the LaTeX/TikZ content would be good, though of course imported logos and graphics would be better.
Otherwise I would look for an external tool that can generate PDFs that I can then include, but that's not as flexible on the day.
Some very useful background is in the preprint Easy colorblind-safe typesetting: General guidelines and a helpful LATEX package, Simon Pfahler TUG2024.  My goals are similar.

related: last weeks TUG meeting had a talk about colourblind-safe typesetting https://tug.org/tug2024/program.html In the discussion, some possible approaches for simulating colour blindness were mentioned, like the possibility to create special colour profiles (but the selection of pdf viewer would be very limited) The recorded stream is available on youtube.

Maybe package colorblind could be useful for colorblind-safe typesetting.

Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122621/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-version-of-a-document-as-seen-by-a-colour-blind-reade ?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm hoping things have moved on since then (strangely I didn't spot that question in my searching, because I forced myself to use the American spelling of "color"!

My goal in this case is to have a single file that works in Adobe Reader (shared Windows systems) and Okular (my Linux machines)

If the simulation doesn't need to be too accurate, you could play around with decodearray to remove colour channels.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz my understanding - and I'm not an expert in the field - is that it's more a remapping of channels that would be needed and I'm not sure how easy that would be.  I'm struggling to find where decodearray is documented.  From usage it appears to be used as an option to \includegraphics but doesn't appear in the graphicx documentation.  It would be a nice half approach if I could either apply it to a full-page PDF image or combine it with a few hand-redefined colours for drawn elements
